# Can't get Restangular remove() to send DELETE request without body

Tags: restangular

I've been working on a webapp, and it was working on localhost. However after deploying to a live site, any DELETE requests get a 400 (bad request) error, with the response '"DELETE" requests may not contain bodies'. Looking at the request, the payload being included is the ID of the object I'm trying to delete. I searched and found a solution to my problem from the Restangular developer [Here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/78#issuecomment-18687759):

```
RestangularProvider.setRequestInterceptor(function(elem, operation) {
   if (operation === "remove") {
      return undefined;
   } 
   return elem;
})
```

However this didn't work for me. I have also tried returning null instead of undefined, yet the request still contains the ID as the body. I put a console.log message inside the if statement and it is displayed before the request response on deletes, so as far as I can tell it's catching delete requests properly. Here is an example of when I'm making a remove call:

```
$scope.delete = function() {
    Restangular.one('graph', $scope.model.id).remove().then(function() {
        $location.path('/');
    });
};
```

I can't figure out what is causing the body to be included in the request, and why the RequestInterceptor isn't fixing the issue. Any help or indication of what is causing this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What you have really looks like it should work. What you can try is using addRequestInterceptor or addFullRequestInterceptor, instead of setRequestInterceptor. setRequestInterceptor is deprecated, but it should still work. Try switching it and let me know if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**addRequestInterceptor** worked for me.

```
 RestangularProvider.addRequestInterceptor(function(elem, operation, what, url) {
            if (operation === "remove") {
                return null;
            }
            return elem;
        });
```